# Inner Join - Registros mas recientes en Tablas

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, sql, mysql-workbench, join

Necesito su apoyo con el siguiente tema:

Lo que pasa es que estoy desarrollando una aplicacion para gestion de llamadas, en dicha aplicaciones existen 3 tablas, "clientes,intentos y datos adicionales", la estructura de las tablas son las siguientes:

Tabla Clientes

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tabla Intentos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tabla Datos Adicionales

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo requiero lograr es un JOIN que me traiga el nombre del cliente de la tabla clientes, pero de la tabla intento me traiga la etiqueta mas reciente de cada usuario y de la tabla datos adicionales me traiga las observaciones tambien la mas reciente de cada usuario.

Lo intente con esta query pero me trae todos y solo quiero el mas reciente

```
SELECT tc.nombre AS nombre_cliente, 
ti.etiqueta AS etiqueta,tda.observaciones AS Comentarios,
tda.fecha_hora_registro AS Fecha_Hora
FROM tbl_clientes tc
LEFT JOIN tbl_intentos ti
ON tc.id_cliente = ti.id_cliente
LEFT JOIN tbl_datos_adicionales tda
ON ti.id_intento = tda.id_intento
WHERE tc.asesor = "asesor1" OR tda.fecha_hora_registro = (SELECT max(tda.fecha_hora_registro))
GROUP BY tda.fecha_hora_registro,tda.id_intento,ti.etiqueta,tc.nombre, tda.observaciones
ORDER BY tda.fecha_hora_registro DESC
;
```

De antemano muchas gracias

Comment: Intenta ordenar desc por id y asi tendras el ultimo en la parte superior de la consulta y para quedarte solo con ese, utiliza un LIMIT de 1.

Comment: ¿Cuál versión de MySQL?

Comment: @Sal es MySQL 8.0

Answer (score 0):

Intenta con *funciones de ventana*, particionando por intento y ordenando for fecha y hora:

```
SELECT c.nombre AS nombre_cliente
     , last_value(i.etiqueta) OVER fi AS etiqueta
     , last_value(da.observaciones) OVER fi AS Comentarios
     , last_value(da.fecha_hora_registro) OVER fi AS Fecha_Hora
  FROM tbl_clientes c
    LEFT JOIN tbl_intentos i
      ON i.id_cliente = c.id_cliente
    LEFT JOIN tbl_datos_adicionales da
      ON da.id_intento = i.id_intento
  WHERE c.asesor = 'asesor1'
  WINDOW fi as ( PARTITION BY i.id_intento
                   ORDER BY i.fecha_de_intento
                          , i.hora_de_intento
               )
```

Comment: Me dice que fi no debe estar en esa position, experando EOF, ;